# Algorithm to determine tournament winners given matrix

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am given an $n\times n$ matrix, $M$, that denotes the outcome of a series of races between $n$ contestants. Each contestant $i$ races against every other contestant $j$ and we say $M_{i,j}=1$ if $i$ beat $j$ (note $M_{i,j}=1\Leftrightarrow M_{j,i}=0$.) We then say that racer $i$ placed in the tournament if they lost at most $10$ races. I am supposed to define an algorithm that is linear in the number of queries made to matrix that returns all of the racers who placed (i.e. lost at most $10$ races.)

In order to reach this algorithm I have noted that the number of placers is bounded by $n=22$. We can thus define an algorithm that will reduce the problem to some case with under $22$ possible candidates and it is possible to brute force from there. I am, however, having trouble reducing the problem to only $22$ contestants. I have tried applying a dynamic programming approach by keeping track of how many races each contestant has won or lost and traversing the matrix diagonally (exploiting the fact that it is symmetric along the diagonal if you invert the values) and thus eventually eliminating $n-22$ of the contestants. I am having trouble showing whether this is indeed linear or, if it is not, how else I may further reduce the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Do you know how to do this with 10 replaced by 0?

Comment: In that case first you could traverse all the entries in the upper diagonal of matrix, and thus eliminate half of the racers since someone loses at each race, and then do something similar but only on entries $M[i,j]$ where $i,j$ have yet to be eliminated. I'm a bit confused on how you could generalize this to the case where you have to observe many more losses in order to eliminate someone.

Comment: Or better stated, I can't seem to figure out how one could apply a similar method when we aren't guaranteed that someone will not place even after losing a match (i.e. how do you reduce the problem and focus on a subset when you must first find $10$ losses.)

Comment: Ok, so you know how to do it with at most 0 losses. Now try to do it with at most 1 loss.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I think I see the pattern of keeping "buckets" for each person and how many losses they have up to this point, and then pitching people in these highest buckets against each other therefore putting one of them one step further. I am, however, failing to see how this would be a linear solution? And also how one may deal with having to make more queries to the matrix if the ones we currently have are not enough to rule people out.

Comment: The way to solve a problem like this is to first solve it for 0 losses, then for 1 loss, and then hopefully in the general case. You already know what to do for 0 losses, so now you have to figure out what to do with 1 loss. Try generalizing your solution for no losses to the case in which one loss is allowed. Give it a few hours.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't proved the general case works yet but your hint was very helpful in getting me to think of the problem correctly.

Comment: The same issue still applies: ​ A n$^2$ algorithm that makes at least $(n^2)/3$ queries to the matrix would be linear _in the number of queries made to the matrix_, although not in n. ​ ​ ​ ​